# How to invoke a webservice in Struts 2

Tags: java, web-services, struts2

I create a sample web service,

how i can invoke this web service in my Struts 2 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the same Way you invoke this web service in other projects.

Answer (score 1):

u can do this by using axis-2 , First u can create stubs from .wsdl url/file they use java class to call stubs